# Database design - saving the entire object to a user or just the id of an object?

Tags: mongodb, database-design

database noob here using MongoDB, in my program, I have users, and the core of my program are these roadmaps that I display. So, each user can create roadmaps, save others roadmaps, blah blah... Each user has a field named savedRoadmaps and createdRoadmaps which should store the roadmaps. My question is, should I just store the roadmap _ids in the savedRoadmap and createdRoadmaps field or the entire roadmap?

I am asking this because it feels like saving just the _id of the roadmaps can save storage, but it might not come in handy when I have to fetch the data of the user first, then fetch the roadmap using the roadmap ID in the user's savedRoadmap/createdRoadmap field, versus just fetching the user and the savedRoadmap field will already have the roadmap in there.

And btw, is there any sweet and brief database design read out there, please direct me to some if you know any!

For a user, I want it to have a name, email, password, description ofcourse, and also savedRoadmaps and createdRoadmaps. A user can create unlimited roadmaps and also save as much as he or she wants.  For a roadmap, I want it to have a name, category, time_completion, author, date, and a roadmap object which will contain the actual json string that I will use d3 to display. Here's my User and Roadmap Schema right now:

---

```
    const RoadmapSchema = new Schema({
  author: {
    type: String,
    require: false
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    require: true
  },
  category: {
    type: String,
    require: true
  },
  time_completion: {
    type: Number,
    require: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  roadmap: {
    type: "object",
    require: true
  }
});
```

and User Schema:

```
    const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  savedRoadmap: {
    type: "object",
    default: []
  },
  createdRoadmap: {
    type: "object",
    default: []
  }
});
```

**My question is, inside of the savedRoadmap and createdRoadmap fields of the User schema, should I include just the _id of a roadmap, or should I include the entire json string which represents the roadmap?**

Comment: Please make clear total requirements of your app. Without knowing this, it's been difficult to modeling schema of mongodb. In your question, i need to know how many roadmap a user can make.AND roadmap contains max number of fields?  After that you can decide whether you do EMBEDDING or making separate collection for roadmap?
Chek https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/ for more details.

Comment: Hi @KaushikDas, sorry for not being specific in my question, I have updated my question, I hope my edition helps you to help me, in short, a user can make unlimited roadmaps and a roadmap object contains a title, category, date, author field, and an actual json string that I can display using d3.js later.

Comment: My current generic comment re "better"/"best" etc: There's no such thing as "better"/"best" in engineering unless you define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should also define "better"/"best". https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461

Comment: Yes, it is time for you to read a textbook on information modeling & database design. Dozens are free online in pdf. However, asking for them is "off-topic". Also, your main question of id vs data is an easily found "duplicate" faq. Eg here try googling just your title with 'site:stackoverflow.com mongodb'. However most such faqs are "too broad" or "opinion based".

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 different data-modeling techniques you can use to design your roadmaps system based on the cardinality of the relationship between `users` and `roadmaps`.

In general you need to de-normalize your data model based *on the queries that are expected from your application*:

- **One to Few:** Embed the N side if the cardinality is one-to-few and there is no need to access the embedded object outside the context of the parent object
- **One to Many:** Use an array of references to the N-side objects if the cardinality is one-to-many or if the N-side objects should stand alone for any reasons
- **One-to-Squillions**: Use a reference to the One-side in the N-side objects if the cardinality is one-to-squillions

> And btw, is there any sweet and brief database design read out there,
>   please direct me to some if you know any!

[Rules of Thumb for MongoDB Schema Design: Part 1](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1)